# kendo datepicker not work well on ie8

Tags: kendo-ui, datepicker, internet-explorer-8

I get something wrong when I use kendo datepicker with ie8, just like picture below.

[image]

My code is simple, in the folder just download from official web,the path is '\telerik.kendoui.professional.2017.2.621.trial\examples\datepicker'

```
            <h4>Show e-mails from:</h4>
            <input id="datepicker" value="10/10/2011" title="datepicker" style="width: 100%" />

            <h4 style="margin-top: 2em;">Add to archive mail from:</h4>
            <input id="monthpicker" value="November 2011" title="monthpicker" style="width: 100%" />
        </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // create DatePicker from input HTML element
            $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker();

            $("#monthpicker").kendoDatePicker({
                // defines the start view
                start: "year",

                // defines when the calendar should return date
                depth: "year",

                // display month and year in the input
                format: "MMMM yyyy",

                // specifies that DateInput is used for masking the input element
                dateInput: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This error you can show explicitly by run the demo as the example folder,any idea can resolve this problem on ie8?

Comment: As of the Kendo UI 2017 R1 release, Internet Explorer 8 is no longer supported. So you will have to use an earlier version of Kendo. See: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/supporting/browser-support

Comment: thank you very much!  as your advise,i  have tryed telerik.kendoui.professional.2016.3.1118,which is also not work well for Internet Explorer 8. After that my friend advised me to find solution in Nopcommerce source code,then i find the version nop use is "2014.1.318". this version could solve my problem and it runs as my expected on  Internet Explorer 8 .